# localStorage IE 11 does not work

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, remote-access, psexec, local-storage

I have a problem with running sites that used localStorage.
I connect to Windows Server 2012 R2 and open IE using cmd with simple site that has access to local storage and all works fine. 
Then I disconnect from the server and connect to Server using Power Shell(WinRM) or PsExec with this command
PsExec \out-oracle -w D:\Deploymen\ D:\Deploymen\Sbt.CMS.Deployment.exe -t True
And this attempt fails.
Why I tried to connect remotely? Because I must run TestCafe UI tests on server from build process when it's finished.
All works fine in Chrome(remotely and directly)? but does not work remotely from IE.
I have done this steps, but it did not help:

- Set for all zones minimal security level
- Enable DOMStorage in register and in browser settings
- Set access level for folders
  “icacls %userprofile%\Appdata\LocalLow /t /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)L”
- Disable Protected and Extended Protected Mode

After remote session I connect to server using RDP and page with localStorage access does not work locally!!!
In one site I found interesting tip, that access to localStorage may be blocked by dllhost process. And when I killed its, all works fine locally again! But not using WinRM or PsExec! 
Ok, I wrote simple console tool, that killed dllhost process before running IE, but PsExec started this process again and again. And so, when I use WinRM, dllhost does not creates again, but localStorage still does not work.
What happened with IE?